# Primes in arithmetic progression

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

We call a prime $p$ "good" if there is $0<k<\log p$ with $2kp+1$ prime. What is the asymptotic density of good primes?

Comment: What is being chosen randomly here - I guess $p$? How is $p$ chosen randomly?

Comment: I modified my message. Thanks

Comment: Call a prime $p$ "good" if there is $k < \log p$ with $2kp+1$ prime. You're asking for the relative asymptotic density of good primes.

Comment: It's a better way to ask my question ...Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "taking randomly a prime number $p$"? What is the probability that you take $p=101$, for example?

Comment: We suppose we know all  prime numbers between $n$ and $2n$. Thus we have a list of numbers and we take one of them randomly.

Comment: We don't need to assume "we know" all primes in that range. You only need to clarify you pick $p$ randomly from that interval. Alternatively, following mathworker's suggestion, ask for the relative asymptotic density.

Comment: It's done . Asymptotic density or relative asymptotic density ... any answer is welcome.

Comment: @EmmanuelGuillemin Do you know what "asymptotic density" and "relative asymptotic density" mean?

Comment: The density of all primes is zero, so as asked, the question is trivial. I think you are more interested in how many good primes there are up to $x$, asymptotically as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: One natural way of understanding this question would be to look at the primes with your property less than or equal to x, divide that by $pi(x)$ and look at that limit.

Comment: I'm not convinced that any purpose is served by insisting that $p$ be prime. One could ask for the density (if it exists) of positive integers $n$ such that the smallest prime $q\equiv1\bmod n$ satisfies $(q-1)/n<2\log n$. Does it really matter whether or not $n$ is prime?

Comment: For Sophie Germain primes it matters.  My question would be a weak version of the conjecture about the infinity of these numbers.